# python yaml path after deployment

Tags: python, yaml

So this is a question about how to handle settings files and relative paths in python (probably also something about best practice).

So I have coded a smaller project that i want to deploy to a docker image and everything is set up now except when I try to run the python task (Through cron) I get the error: `settings/settings.yml` not found.

```
tree .
├───settings
│   └───settings/settings.yml
└───main.py
```

And am referencing the yml file as

```
open('settings/settings.yml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

I can see this is what is causing the problem but am unsure about how to fix it. I wish to reference the main file basically by using the `entry_points` from `setuptools` in the future so my quick fix with cd'ing before python main.py will not be a lasting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding a path as a string, you can find the directories and build the file path with `os.path`. For example:

```
import os
import yaml

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
settings_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "settings")
filename = "settings.yml"
settings_path = os.path.join(settings_dir, filename)
with open(settings_path, "r") as infile:
    settings_data = yaml.load(infile)
```

This way it can be run in any file system and the python file can be called from any directory.

Comment: Now an extension to the problem what if I want to reference the same settings file from a dir that is underneath the main dir i.e.:
the new dir is same level as settings and want to ref the settings.yml from within this dir in a method called from main